# Python OpenSSL : Importerror : cannot import name integer_types

Tags: python, linux, cassandra, redhat, importerror

Need to execute the following procedure on a Red Hat server:
http://www.datastax.com/documentation/opscenter/5.1/opsc/configure/opscEnableSSLtar.html

Python is version 2.7.9 - installed with Makefile.

However, we're encountering an error when trying to validate the OpenSSL version.  Need advice on how to proceed from here.  It was previously suggested to install Python six to fix compatibility issues, but there was no improvement.

> % python -c "import OpenSSL; print OpenSSL._version_"
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in < module >
>     File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/OpenSSL/**init**.py", line 8, in < module >
>     File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/OpenSSL/rand.py", line 9, in < module >
>   ImportError: cannot import name integer_types